# Which Amazon service do I need for simple querying of book titles, ISBN, and publishers?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

There are so many services now, and a lot of search results about the topic talk about services that have been deprecated. I'm only doing this for the first time now. I have a little library app in C# that I want to use to query Amazon services to update book cover picture, ISBN, authors, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the ItemLookup operation of the Amazon Associates Web Service (previously called the Amazon E-Commerce Service). More info [here](http://aws.amazon.com/associates/) and [here](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1661&categoryID=19).

Answer (score -1):

How about [LINQ to Amazon](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2006/06/26/introducing-linq-to-amazon.aspx) ;-p

(see also [how it works](http://linqinaction.net/blogs/main/archive/2006/06/28/Linq_to_Amazon_implementation_fore_steps.aspx), and the [source](http://linqinaction.net/files/folders/linqinaction/entry1952.aspx))

Comment: Sure, but that in turn talks to a service under the hood. I wanted a service, not an API :)